# PyMedia cannot read the duration of file

Tags: python

```
clip = VideoFileClip("http://tv.wirtualnemedia.pl/movie/9636x6379dc85554e71ebc4b8298524b42c96.mp4")
```

I'm trying this simple call, but it fails

```
MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file http://tv.wirtualnemedia.pl/movie/9636x6379dc85554e71ebc4b8298524b42c96.mp4.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 2.4.2-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct  9 2014 07:24:56 with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.3-11)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-shared -- disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-ffserver --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --cc=gcc-4.8
libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[tcp @ 0x3874be0] Failed to resolve hostname tv.wirtualnemedia.pl: 
System error
http://tv.wirtualnemedia.pl/movie/9636x6379dc85554e71ebc4b8298524b42c96.mp4: Input/output error
```

Do you have any ideas? I need to create a thumnbail from 'remote' video url

Comment: I'd say that `Failed to resolve hostname tv.wirtualnemedia.pl`is a fairly clear steer. Can you access this URL from outside of Python?

Comment: I access this URL via browser. And paste this url to my video tag. And it works.

Comment: In that case, you might want to re-phrase your question, as the root cause is actually that `ffmpeg` cannot resolve the hostname - it's not specifically a pymedia issue. As a debugging step, you could try replacing `tv.wirtualnemedia.pl` with `149.202.156.236` (the IP address I get from pinging that hostname)

Comment: Also, your problem may be to do with the fact that the URL you have is not actually a link to a video file (which `ffmpeg` will expect), but a web-page with an embedded video-player.